# 13.1.H. from FOAG

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

This is from Vakil's FOAG,13.1.H,page 372:[image]

Is the answer to use transition functions on $Y$ then pull them back on $X$ and glue them together like what we do when treat vector bundle?If it's right,is there any way not using transition functions?

Comment: That's the right idea (certainly how you would do it in the manifold setting), but you would have to essentially "conjugate" this process using the functor from locally free sheaves to vector bundles. The standard way to do this directly with sheaves is to start with the inverse image sheaf $\pi^{-1} \mathcal G$ and do *something* to turn it into an $\mathcal O_X$-module. I won't say any more because I think Ravi wants you to figure that out yourself.

Comment: I get it,thank you.